# Redirect URL with parameters to other domain with same parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect permanent from something like this
http://www.example.de/page.html?cid=00340119050014953926&pc=70000

to this
http://www.secondexample.com/?cid=00340119050014953926&pc=70000

So it's a different domain without the "page.html" but with the same parameters.

Is it possible to do this with RedirectPermanent or do I need RewriteRule?

EDIT: 
Problem is that I only want to redirect if the URL has parameters but not if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `RedirectPermanent`, but reading some documentation it doesn't seem to be much different than `RewriteRule ... [R=301]`.

You can accomplish what you want with (untested code):

```
RewriteCond %QUERY_STRING ^(.+)$
RewriteRule page\.html http://www.secondexample.com/?%1 [R=301]
```

I believe you could do this even without the trailing `?%1` as it appends the original query string to the new url if no `?` is present. This RewriteRule matches if the requested page is `page.html`. It then checks if the RewriteCond is true (that is, the regex matches the query string), in this case if the query string is at least 1 character long. If this is the case, it rewrites the url and redirects the page with code 301 (moved permanently). `%1` is a backreference to the first capturing group in a condition, but as said earlier, probably not necessary.